# Unable to access CentOS setup Network Configuration after attempting Python update

Tags: networking, centos, python

I attempted to update Python on my CentOS 5.6 VM and have encountered some issues afterward. Initially, `yum` wouldn't work, but I have resolved that.

However, now I am unable to access the Network Configuration section under `setup`.

When I do select this option, I see this at the command line:

```
[root@crmpicco ~]# setup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/system-config-network-tui", line 9, in <module>
    from snack import *
ImportError: No module named snack
```

Line 9 on that file is this:

`from snack import *`

I'm not familiar with Python (I'm a PHP developer), so I'm not sure where to go with this or how to fix it.

This is what I have installed relating to Python:

```
[root@crmpicco ~]# yum list installed | grep python
MySQL-python.x86_64                      1.2.1-1                       installed
audit-libs-python.x86_64                 1.7.18-2.el5                  installed
dbus-python.x86_64                       0.70-9.el5_4                  installed
gamin-python.x86_64                      0.1.7-8.el5                   installed
gnome-python2.x86_64                     2.16.0-1.fc6                  installed
gnome-python2-bonobo.x86_64              2.16.0-1.fc6                  installed
gnome-python2-canvas.x86_64              2.16.0-1.fc6                  installed
gnome-python2-gnomevfs.x86_64            2.16.0-1.fc6                  installed
libselinux-python.x86_64                 1.33.4-5.7.el5                installed
libxml2-python.x86_64                    2.6.26-2.1.2.8.el5_5.1        installed
libxslt-python.x86_64                    1.1.17-2.el5_2.2              installed
mod_python.x86_64                        3.2.8-3.1                     installed
python.x86_64                            2.4.3-43.el5                  installed
python-devel.i386                        2.4.3-43.el5                  installed
python-devel.x86_64                      2.4.3-43.el5                  installed
python-elementtree.x86_64                1.2.6-5                       installed
python-iniparse.noarch                   0.2.3-4.el5                   installed
python-libs.x86_64                       2.4.3-43.el5                  installed
python-numeric.x86_64                    23.7-2.2.2                    installed
python-sqlite.x86_64                     1.1.7-1.2.1                   installed
python-urlgrabber.noarch                 3.1.0-6.el5                   installed
python26.x86_64                          2.6.8-2.el5                   installed
python26-libs.x86_64                     2.6.8-2.el5                   installed
rpm-python.x86_64                        4.4.2.3-22.el5                installed
```

Also, it would seem I am now on Python 2.6.8.

`python --version` gives me 
`Python 2.6.8`

Comment: it looks like you iunstall python but not the module used by `setup`. What gives you the command : `yum list installed | grep python` ? and how do you updated your python version ?

Comment: @Kiwy I have updated the question to include which Python packages I have installed. I can't find in my history how I installed Python, but to fix `yum` it I had to point to `/usr/bin/python` instead of `/usr/bin/python2.4` (or whatever version it updated to). Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: As you've discovered, Python is absolutely central to Red Hat derived Linuxes. I would recommend *not* upgrading it, short of upgrading the whole OS. The whole idea behind a "stable" Linux like CentOS is that you use it as a stable platform to build something else on top of. That means leaving the platform untouched, in the same way that you don't try to change your house's foundation after you build the house.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Sadly it's a bit late for that as I _have_ changed it. Do you know how to revert or fix this issue?

Comment: Go to a directory containing the distribution packages, then `rpm -ivh --force *python*`. That's probably a bit heavy-handed, but it's a faster path back to a working system than trying to get it working with an unsupported version of Python.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Thanks for the comment - where will I find them? Are you referring to the `.rpm` files?

Comment: On your installation CD, or on centos.org, or on a mirror, or...

Comment: @WarrenYoung Are you referring to a directory on my filesystem? I assume you are as you've said yo run the `rpm` command. It is a VM I am working on, so no CDs unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15379/discussion-between-warren-young-and-crmpicco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this on my CentOS 5.6 installation I did the following:

```
wget http://vault.centos.org/5.6/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-2.4.3-43.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh --force python-2.4.3-43.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is complaining about missing a specific python module (library):

```
ImportError: No module named snack
```

On my Debian, `snack.py` is provided by the `python-newt` package. A quick search of the [CentOS repositories](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/) suggests that this is called `newt-python` in CentOS. So, try installing that:

```
yum install newt-python
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me `Setting up Install Process. No package newt-python available. Nothing to do`. Where can I find what repo this is part of? I should point out i'm on CentOS **5.6**. Everything online suggests this is CentOS 6 and above.

Comment: `yum search newt` ?

Comment: @crmpicco sorry, I don't use CentOS. Try kiwy's suggestion above, that should help you locate the package if it exists.

Comment: @Kiwy Thanks, I had already tried a `yum search` but that only brought up perl and devel modules. I assume the python version is part of another repo - but I have no idea which one. Is it for CentOS 6 only?

Comment: @terdon It would seem it is part of another repo (that I don't have). Would you know how I could locate this?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, is to reinstall all library in version 2.6 and maybe uninstall `python 2.4` but **I'm not sure about that part**.
The problem is now you have `Python 2.6` installed and probably use by default, while you have almost none of the following libraries for `python 2.6` (that were installed for `python 2.4`:

```
libselinux-python.x86_64 
libxml2-python.x86_64    
libxslt-python.x86_64       
python.x86_64            
python-devel.i386        
python-devel.x86_64      
python-elementtree.x86_64
python-iniparse.noarch   
python-libs.x86_64       
python-numeric.x86_64    
python-sqlite.x86_64     
python-urlgrabber.noarch
```

I suggest you to either remove `python 2.6` (but that's probably not what you want, either install all those missing library for `python  2.6` like this:

```
yum install libselinux-python26.x86_64 
yum install libxml2-python26.x86_64    
yum install libxslt-python26.x86_64    
yum install mod_python26.x86_64        
yum install python26.x86_64            
yum install python26-devel.i386        
yum install python26-devel.x86_64      
yum install python26-elementtree.x86_64
yum install python26-iniparse.noarch   
yum install python26-libs.x86_64       
yum install python26-numeric.x86_64    
yum install python26-sqlite.x86_64     
yum install python26-urlgrabber.noarch
```

I can't warranty the success of such an installation, but that's the spirit. because `python 2.6` miss the library aka module in python to work correctly.